# Visual Studio Online (VSO) Branch Policies - Pull Request w/ Auto Build

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, azure-pipelines

I’m trying to accomplish a complete CI solution and it will start with the PR, -> build ->, build pushes the nuget packages to octopus -> octopus recognizes the new package and deploys.  I wanted some clarification on how the Pull Request policy works for Automatically build pull requests.  We have selected the *“When team members create or update a pull request into the “dev” branch, queue this build : MyCoolBuilDefinition”.*

I noticed that once a PR is created the build fires immediately.  It creates a temp git branch “refs/pull/123/merge”.  I assume it creates a pre-merge on this branch to do the build.  Is this a build we can deploy and test? Or is this just to satisfy the build policy?

I’m concerned that if there are 3 pull request created....If PR1 and PR2 have already been built but not marked Completed.  Will PR3’s build contain code from PR1 and PR2?  Because the code is only merged into the “dev” branch when the PR is marked as Completed…I would think not. The pre-merge should pull from the latest “dev” branch to do the pre-merge.  And, if P1 and p2 have not been marked Completed, then P3 will not have P1 and P2 code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build is just used to satisfy the build policy and your concern is right. The pre-merge does not include the changes in other uncompleted pull request. It just make sure the current pull request can be built successfully. So you'e better to create two build definitions for "dev" branch. One definition just build the code to satisfy the pull request, the another one enable continuous integration and build the code and push the nuget packages.

Comment: thank you.  This is the route I was going.  All is good, now.